# How can I run individual tests using Check?

Tags: c, unit-testing

[Check docs explains how to selectively run test suites or test cases](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_4.html#Selective-Running-of-Tests), but not how to selectively run individual tests. My test cases can contain dozens of tests, so when debugging using `printf` statements that just produces a mess.

I need to be able to run specific tests, preferably by name, e.g.:

```
CK_RUN_TEST=check_readbuf_allocation make check
```

The hypothetical `CK_RUN_TEST` environment variable would cause only the test function `check_readbuf_allocation` to be executed.

Each individual test is completely separate from all other tests by design, so I see no reason why this shouldn't be possible.

Is there any way to run individual tests short of creating a whole new executable with all the Check boilerplate code for every test function?

Comment: There's no such support. You'd have to create a new TCase for every test function, and use the CK_RUN_TCASE env variable. (Albeit it looks trivial to add this capability to the check library)

Comment: @nos: I considered that possibility for a few seconds, but it'll require way too much boilerplate code. Although, I could possibly concoct some macros to reduce it. Meanwhile: [check / Feature Requests / #31 Add CK_RUN_TEST environment variable for running specific test functions](https://sourceforge.net/p/check/feature-requests/31/)